# Beanstalk like Functionality

Tags: svn, version-control, beanstalk-svn

I'm finally getting my team to embrace source code management now that we're working on projects where more than one dev is touching the same codebase, and I setup a free/trial account on Beanstalk for hosted Subversion so people could get a taste of how it works.

That said, we've discussed a somewhat ambitious plan to put a lot of needed/wanted functionality into a single server we can run ourselves, and while I think that's great, we're still working without SCM as those plans slowly form.

In the interim, I'd like to setup a temporary SVN server, but was wondering if there are any F/OSS packages that we could setup that would provide Beanstalk like functionality (i.e. the nice web interface/management setup).  I'm not overly concerned with the core-language of the package unless I'd need to hack on the code for the system itself, in which case I'm reasonably comfortable with PHP, Perl, and .NET, though I could probably pickup (an)other language(s) as needed.  That said, I'd like to steer clear of .NET or any other technology that would necessitate a Windows license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a lot of people on Stack Overflow who know lots about Subversion, but have never heard of Beanstalk and therefore can't help you. Specifically what web front-end functionality are you looking for?

My team only ever needs to browse our SVN repositories via a web browser (and compare revisions) and for that we use [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/). It's simple and not especially fully-featured, but it does the job for us. You can't use WebSVN to create repositories, but since that's a very simple job, and one that is done relatively infrequently, that's probably not an issue, is it?